# Yarn datatables package with custom plugins

Tags: tinymce, customization, yarnpkg

So Im using yarn to install packages. The one in question is TinyMCE. This package has a plugins folder and we have previously created our own plugins. Now that Yarn is managing the package is there a way to integrate my own plugins without yarn wiping them out if we update, or some way for Yarn to ignore that folder during updates/install etc

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend placing your custom plugins outside of the TinyMCE code bundle and using the `external_plugins` setting to reference your plugins:

https://www.tinymce.com/docs/configure/integration-and-setup/#external_plugins

This will allow you to update TinyMCE whenever you like without fear of overwriting or deleting your custom plugins.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend creating a folder structure like tinymce/plugins/<plugin_name>/plugin.js in your asset folder.
In this folder you can put all your custom plugins

Put the following code in webpack.config.js:

```
.addPlugin(new CopyWebpackPlugin({
        patterns: [
            { from: './assets/tinymce/plugins', to: 'plugins' },
        ],
    }))
```

and register your plugin like

```
tinymce.PluginManager.add('<plugin_name>', function(editor, url) {
...
})
```

Then in tinymce put:

```
tinymce.init({
    selector: '.tiny',
    plugins: ['link', 'anchor', 'code', '<plugin_name>'],
....
});
```

run `yarn encore dev`